# Which sport is much better as in burning fat faster without making muscles?

Tags: fat-loss, sports

I want to choose a sport among with a diet to start losing fat again. I want to know which sport is better to start with e.g. basketball, swimming, badminton, volleyball, gym, skate.

Comment: If you're untrained, any sport you do is going to make you stronger and give you more muscle. Why do you want to avoid building any muscle? Building some muscle will help you lose fat.

Comment: This is a common misconception among women... They don't want to workout because they think they'll look like Venus William after they hit the gym.

Comment: AFAIK you build different types of muscles when running or doing weight lifting. Right? That can easily influence your choice of sports...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://www.nutristrategy.com/caloriesburned.htm) is a list of sports and the average calories lost whilst taking part in them.

Running, skiing, diving and cycling seem to lost the highest calories.

However the best sport is probably one that you will do. The more you enjoy it, the more likely you will keep at it. Which ones do you enjoy the most?

Answer (score 2):

Any sport where you are working hard will burn calories and fat. The more muscle you have the faster you will lose fat. The more you sweat, the faster you will burn calories and fat. Sprinting and lifting heavy weights are good for burning fat. You are not going become huge and muscular without trying really hard if that's what you are worried about.

Comment: +1. Trying very hard *to gain muscle* as well as eating very hard, I'd venture to say.

Answer (score 0):

An hour of cardio will burn more calories than an hour of weightlifting. However, the muscle built from an hour of weightlifting will allow your basal metabolic rate to increase which is the amount of calories you burn at rest.

Any exercise will make muscles.  That's a good thing.